# how to make all plots the same height?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqtgraph

So I have several (it changes) plots that are stacked vertically.  They all have the same x-axes, so I only show the x-axis labels on the bottom plot since if there are a large number of plots, repeating the x-axis labels clutters things up.  What this ends up doing however is making the bottom plot area smaller because the labels take up some area (the plotItems are the same size I think)

I can't seem to figure out how to make it so all the plot areas (viewboxes) are the same size.  Any suggestions?

[image]

Here is some simple code that will reproduce the problem...

```
from pyqtgraph.Qt import QtGui, QtCore
import numpy as np
import pyqtgraph as pg

app = QtGui.QApplication([])


win = pg.GraphicsWindow(title="Basic plotting examples")
win.resize(1000,600)


p1 = win.addPlot(y=np.random.normal(size=100), pen=(255,0,0))
p1.getAxis('bottom').setStyle(showValues=False)
win.nextRow()
p2 = win.addPlot(y=np.random.normal(size=100))
p2.getAxis('bottom').setStyle(showValues=False)
win.nextRow()
p3 = win.addPlot(y=np.random.normal(size=100), pen=(0,0,255))
p3.setLabel('bottom', "Time (s)")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    QtGui.QApplication.instance().exec_()
```

Comment: provide a [mcve]

Comment: Note that this problem gets even worse if `win.nextRow()     win.addLabel()` is used instead of `p3.setLabel()`, which I did not expect.

Comment: fwiw I'm still looking for a solution to this problem.